# Script doesn't change after deploying site on Firebase. Same error persists

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, firebase-hosting

I have a website that is hosted by Firebase on which I badly commented some lines of code. That code has been fixed and deployed but the problem persists.

I changed an aspect of the HTML to see if the website gets deployed at all whenever I tell it to and that changed in a few seconds. The error is still there though and if I go in the console and click on the line the error should be on it still shows me my old script which is now fixed.

code my error points to(this is what it actually looked like about 5 deploys ago): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odius.jpg

actual code (removed the comments) (/public/assets/js/login.js): https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5I33.jpg

I expected the error to go away after deploying as the site is actually updating its files as I saw after testing it with the HTML element but all I get is the `login.js:56 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` error because the comment is badly placed.

EDIT: This solution worked for me: [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is likely because you need to hard refresh (e.g. bust cache) to see your new site.

In chrome, there is an option to disable caching while you have dev tools open. You should enable that option, refresh the site with dev tools open, and see if your problem persists.